# Import PDF files from laptop to iPad without network

Tags: ipad, pdf, sharing

We can use iTunes to import PDF files to Books application of iPad. However Books application has no PDF annotation capability. I have installed other PDF viewers on iPad (like Documents by Readdle, Foxit PDF viewer, etc) but have no idea how to import my PDF files from laptop to these applications, without network services (iCloud, Dropbox, email, etc).

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After connecting iPad to iTunes select the "Apps" tab. Scroll to the bottom of the page where there should be a section labeled "File Sharing". Those PDF viewing (and annotating) apps should be listed under there. Select the app, and then choose "Add..." from the lower right corner of the box. Add the PDFs and sync to your iPad.